# Appending data for every occurance for the same event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am appending some `php files using ajax` every time the user `scrolls to the bottom` of the window.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100){
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
    // Function to append php files using ajax
    }
})
```

I want to recognize the next time user scrolls to bottom of the page and append some other php files, but how do I find out the next(1 or many) events that scroll to bottom of the page?

```
Example: First scroll to bottom: Append 1.php 2.php
         second scroll to bottom: append 3.php 4.php
         third scroll to bottom: append 5.php 6.php
         4th scroll to bottom: show footer
```

I dont need `infinite scroll plugin`. Because there is no concept of `footer` there.

Comment: Why not simply count it...?

Comment: I did it does not work properly.... I was having an if statement to execute a block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a counter variable which counts how many requests you've made. You can then pass that to the server which will then return the required information. Something like this:

```
var requestCount = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        // Function to append php files using ajax
        requestCount++;
        if (requestCount < 4) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'foo.php',
                data: { page: requestCount },
                success: function() {
                    // append your items
                }
            }
        }    
        else {
            // show footer
        }
    }
})
```

In your PHP you would need to take the `page` variable and return the relevant items.

Comment: It soes not solve my problem, I'l accept it just to reduce answers

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100){
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
        if(count<4)
            // Function to append php files using ajax
            call_your_ajax_with_url(count+'.php');
            call_your_ajax_with_url(count+1 +'.php');
            count+=1;
        else showFooter();
    }
});
```

would do the work.